# Matching and removing recurring group of words using REGEX in SAS

Tags: regex, sas

I am trying to remove group of repeating words in SAS. Basically, I am trying to remove set of words that reoccur. Forward slash is the delimeter. I am using SAS 9.4 and have the following example:

I tried the above regex and it works for 'Lymph node pain/Lymph node pain/Pain in extremity'. The result is 'Lymph node pain/Pain in extremity'. However it doesn't work for 'Lymph node pain/Pain in extremity/Pain in extremity' and 'Lymph node pain/Neuralgia/Neuralgia'. I'm not sure why.

> ```
> data have;
>   string = 'Lymph node pain/Pain in extremity/Pain in extremity';output;
>   string = 'Lymph node pain/Lymph node pain/Pain in extremity'; output;
>   string = 'Lymph node pain/Neuralgia/Neuralgia'; output;
> run;
>
> data test;
>   set have;
>      _1=prxparse('s/([A-Za-z].+?\s.*?\/.*?)(.*?)(\1+)/\2\3/i');
>      _2=prxparse('/([A-Za-z].+?\s.*?\/.*?)(.*?)(\1+)/i');
>     do i=1 to 10;
>         string=prxchange(_1, -1, strip(string));
>         if not prxmatch(_2, strip(string)) then leave;
>     end;
>    drop i  ;
> run;
> ```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you open to a `scan`-based approach? It would involve a bit more code but it might be slightly easier to follow than a monster regex.

Comment: Also, what's the desired output if you have something like `A/B/A` - i.e. repeated but non-consecutive instances of the same phrase?

Comment: @user667489, sure I'd like to see another idea. Although I am a big fan of regex and like every opportunity to learn and improve. If A/B/A then result should be A/B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `scan`-based approach. I've assumed that you have a max of 3 phrases per string, but this can easily be adjusted to work for any number of phrases if necessary.

```
data have;
  string = 'Lymph node pain/Pain in extremity/Pain in extremity';output;
  string = 'Lymph node pain/Lymph node pain/Pain in extremity'; output;
  string = 'Lymph node pain/Neuralgia/Neuralgia'; output;
  string = 'Neuralgia/Lymph node pain/Neuralgia'; output;  /*Added A/B/A example*/
run;

data test;
  set have;
  array phrases[3] $32;
  /*Separate string into an array of phrases delimited by / */
  do i = 1 to dim(phrases);
    phrases[i] = scan(string,i,'/');
  end;
  /*Sort the array so that duplicate phrases are next to each other*/
  call sortc(of phrases[*]);
  /*Iterate through the array and build up an output string of non-duplicates*/
  length outstring $255;
  do i = 1 to dim(phrases);
    if i = 1 then outstring = phrases[1];
    else if phrases[i] ne phrases[i-1] then outstring = catx('/',outstring,phrases[i]);
  end;
  keep string outstring;
run;
```

This has the side effect of sorting all the phrases into alphabetical order rather than order of first appearance in the string.

Comment: This is a very nice way to achieve the same result. Thanks. Hopefully someone can still tell me what's wrong with the REGEX though.